# zone.afterTask and zone.beforeTask hook methods not working

Tags: angular, zone

I'm trying to implement simple `zone.afterTask` and `beforeTask` hooks but though *code ain't throwing any error* , those methods are never getting called.

I searched Zone [repo in github](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) , and couldn't find any reference to these methods in the source code apart from the ones that's used in the example. [counting example](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/example/js/counting-zone.js) does use `afterTask` and `beforeTask` but I've set a debugger and saw those methods are never getting called in their example as well .

**It looks like these methods have been deprecated** , If not kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code -

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  template: `
      <div>
        <p>Basic use of Zone</p>
        <button (click)="startTask()">Start Task</button>
        <p> Time taken {{timeTaken}}</p>
      </div>
    `
})
export class HelloZone {
  timeTaken: any;

  task1(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++);
  }

  startTask() {
    let startTime;

    let myZone = Zone.parent.fork({
      beforeTask: function() {
        startTime = new Date();
      },
      afterTask: function() {
        this.timeTaken = new Date() - startTime;
      }
    });
    myZone.run(function(){
      this.task1();
      setTimeout(this.task1, 2000);
      this.task1();
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for your use case, you can leverage `onInvokeTask` and `onHasTask` hooks as described below:

```
export class HelloZone {
  timeTaken: any;

  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {

  }

  (...)

  startTask() {
    let startTime;

    let myZone = Zone.current.fork({
      onInvokeTask: (parent, current, target, task) => {
        startTime = new Date();
        parent.invokeTask(target, task);
      },
      onHasTask: (parent, current, target, hasTask) => {
        if (!hasTask.macroTask) {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.timeTaken = new Date() - startTime;
          });
        }
      }
    });
    myZone.run(() => {
      this.task1();
      setTimeout(this.task1, 2000);
      this.task1();
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/EH8uy66ke1i61QhE9fYi?p=preview.

Comment: That partially answers my question. Main reason that they are not working is *after v0.5 those API's are deprecated*